# MySql import data into table

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis

How long does it take to upload csv data into MySql database table which consists of around 300,000 rows and 12 columns.
In my case it is taking more than 15 minutes and it is still importing, should i cancel it or do i have any wrong setting or is it just normal, please let me know.

Comment: Impossible to advise given we don't know your system, and you haven't told us how you are importing or doing so over a network.

Comment: Depends on many factors - the data size, the presence of initial data, indexes, triggers... may vary from 3-5 second and up to infinite.